# Confusion about strings in C

Tags: c, string

Char arrays have continuously confused me in C.

Here is the following code:

```
char tcp_port[100], udp_port[6];
tcp_port[99] = '\0'; udp_port[5] = '\0';
fscanf(fp, " tcp_port=%s", tcp_port);
fscanf(fp, " udp_port=%s", udp_port);
printf("%s\n", tcp_port); printf("%s\n", udp_port);
```

This works and prints out the right number. However, since `tcp_port` has 100 elements, how do those just disappear when printing? The port is only 5 characters long and the last element is null terminated. Does printf just ignore those unintialized elements, and do those uninitialized elements contain random data?

Comment: `do those uninitialized elements contain random data` yes, these elements contain random data

Comment: I explain what C strings are in [Arbitrary length string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918363/2157640).

Comment: @Lashane: Strictly speaking, they don't contain *random* data, they contain *arbitrary* data.

Comment: @KeithThompson agree, very important difference, especially for this question. poteito potato

Comment: The C standard defines a *string* as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `printf()` only prints the characters up to the first `\0` character. All C string functions do this. They also automatically append that `\0` character when necessary, like the `scanf()` function there. That's why it's called a "0-terminated string".

The other elements can contain anything and they will be completely ignored. In practice, they usually contain random junk, but it depends on a variety of factors.

Note that when you allocate memory you must keep that `\0` character in mind. Your `tcp_port` string can only at most 99 characters, because the last one must be 0.

Comment: Another point here is that `fscanf(3)` puts `\0` to the end of the scanned string.